# Inserting image/object in pyplot.table

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cell_text = [
                ['56', '85', '84', '52', '90', '102', '133'],
                ['93', '95', '63', '117', '126', '100', '91'],
                ['60', '30', '30', '11', '10', '1', '33']
            ]
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
rows = ["test1","test2","test3"]
the_table = plt.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      cellLoc = 'center',
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=None,
                      colLabels=cols,
                      loc='bottom')
```

Is there a way to insert an image or an object such as `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((50,100),40,30,linewidth=1,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')` into the table next to a row label text? I've tried for example

```
rows = [matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((50,100),40,30,linewidth=1,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none'),"test2","test3"]
```

but this just displays as `Rectangle(xy=(50,100),width=40,height=30,angle=0)` inside the cell.

Motivation: I'm trying to create a presentable form of https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/table_demo.html but with legend markers (small rectangles) instead of coloring the cell with the respective bar colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "insert" an object into a table cell in matplotlib. A table cell is a rectangle with a text associated.

While it would be possible to write a custom cell that has an object associated and position that object at drawtime, it seems an easier solution here is to use unicode characters in the shape of the desired object. This prevents the need for pretty complicated subclassing of table cells etc.

So for example you could use the `shapes = ["◼", "◀", "●"]` to use as markers for a scatter plot, as well as texts elements in table cells.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cell_text = [
                ['56', '85', '84', '52', '90', '102', '133'],
                ['93', '95', '63', '117', '126', '100', '91'],
                ['60', '30', '30', '11', '10', '1', '33']
            ]
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
rows = ["test1","test2","test3"]
shapes = ["◼", "◀", "●"]
colors = ["crimson", "indigo", "limegreen"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, left=0.15)
ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, bottom=False)

for y, s, c in zip(cell_text, shapes, colors):
    ax.scatter(cols, np.array(y).astype(float), c=c, marker=f"${s}$")
ax.set_xlim(-0.5,len(cols)-0.5)

table = ax.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      cellLoc = 'center',
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=None,
                      colLabels=cols,
                      loc='bottom')
height = table.get_celld()[0,0].get_height()

for i in range(len(rows)):
    cell = table.add_cell(i+1, -2, width=0.07, height=height, text=shapes[i], 
                          loc="center")
    cell.get_text().set_color(colors[i])

plt.show()
```

[image]